# How can I create columns from rows in a pandas dataframe (Python 3.7)?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, pdf, pypdf

I would like to restructure a pandas dataframe from long to wide according to the data in the dataframe rows. I have a pandas dataframe of the following form:

| item_type | item_content | meet_mins_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | THE BOARD OF EDUCATION \nOF THE |
| NaN | NaN | LONG BEACH UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT \n \n... |
| NaN | NaN | \nA regular meeting of the Board ... |
| NaN | NaN | Present: Members Craighead, Kerr, ... |
| NaN | NaN | Call to \nOrder \n |
| NaN | NaN | President Kerr called the meeting to ... |
| NaN | NaN | Closed \nSession \n |
| NaN | NaN | President Kerr announced that the Boar... |
| NaN | NaN | Call to \nOrder |
| NaN | NaN | Having completed the Closed Session, P... |
| NaN | NaN | Report of \nClosed \nSession \n |
| NaN | NaN | President Kerr reported that the Gover... |
| NaN | NaN | Public \nHearing \n \nRes. 071618-C, \nDe... |
| NaN | NaN | President Kerr announced the public he... |
| NaN | NaN | Call for \nAgenda \nItems/ \nAdopt \n... |
| NaN | NaN | President Kerr asked if Board Members ... |
| NaN | NaN | Approval \n of \nMinutes |
| NaN | NaN | It was moved by Member Meyer that th... |
| NaN | NaN | Communi-\ncations \n |
| NaN | NaN | Member Craighead recognized Mary Pallad... |

From the dataframe preview above, I would like certain values of `meet_mins_content` to instead serve as values for `item_type` with the row immediately below serving as the value for `item_content`. I know the list of the values that I would like to go into `item_type`: "Call to \nOrder \n", "Closed \nSession \n", "Call to \nOrder", "Report of \Closed Session \n", and "Approval \n of \nMinutes". For each of these, the row immediately below should populate the corresponding cell for `item_content` -- for example, the first row in my dataframe should be `item_type` == "Call to \nOrder \n" and `item_content`. It is OK to keep `meet_mins_content` for now, though I would eventually like to delete it.

Here is the kind of dataframe that I am looking for:

| item_type | item_content | meet_mins_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Call to \nOrder \n | President Kerr called the meeting to ... | THE BOARD OF EDUCATION \nOF THE |
| Closed \nSession \n | President Kerr announced that the Boar... | Closed \nSession \n |
| Purchasing \n& Contract \nReport | Member Meyer moved approval of the Pu... | Closed \nSession \n |
| Citizens' Bond \nOversight \nComte. \n | Member Williams moved Approval of Memb... | Closed \nSession \n |

Is there a way to pass a list of values that can accomplish the task I have outlined? Happy to share more code about where this data came from (a parsed PDF).

Comment: maybe give an example of wanted output, that will help

Comment: It's a bit difficult, as @DaSong notes, to tell exactly what you want. I'd suggest digging into the pandas docs -- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html -- between the slicing, groupby and drop features for examples, should get you close to where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks, @Da Song -- I added an example per your suggestion. Mr. J appreciate the tip -- I'll poke around pandas. A big part of my challenge is just conceptualizing a good approach.